# Show contiguous time periods without data in Libre Calc pivot table, pivot chart?

Tags: pivot-table, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc, date, pivot-chart

A minimal example: our table has sales in 2015, 2017, but not 2016.

```
Date        Sales
01/02/15    $500
10/11/17    $1000
```

You make a Pivot Table:

- Data > Pivot Table > Create
- Row Fields: Date
- Data Fields: Sum - Sales

Group the "Date" column:

- Go to Pivot Table (e.g., tab "Pivot Table_Sheet1_1")
- Select "01/02/15" cell
- Data > Group and Outline > Group > Group by

  - Intervals: Years

Only the years 2015 and 2017 appear in the Pivot Table, but not 2016.

```
Date            Sum - Sales
2015            $500.00
2017            $1,000.00
Total Result    $1,500.00
```

---

Make a Pivot Chart:

- Insert > Chart
- Choose a Chart Type: Line
- Click "Finish"

This chart is misleading without 2016 $0 sales point.

**How can we make 2016 (and maybe even other time periods until present period, e.g., 2018) appear in the table and any corresponding Pivot Charts?**

---

Notes:

- Although [this is possible](http://www.howtoexcelatexcel.com/excel-tips-tricks/show-zero-values-in-a-pivot-table/) in MS [Excel](https://www.excel-university.com/show-pivottable-months-without-data/), I specifically seek a solution in Libre Calc
- I specifically seek an "automatic" solution that persists even as users change underlying data and "Refresh" Pivot Table